# Data aggregation function on date diff

Tags: mysql

I have a scenario in which I have to get an average of day differences grouped by person id.

```
select AVG(DATEDIFF(max(date1),max(date2)))
from tableName
group by personID;
```

This query doesn't work. I need help on this.

Comment: r u getting any kind of error? if so plz mention

Comment: Error: Invalid use of group function

Comment: I was able to recreate this if one (or both) of the dates are the result of `MAX` (or `MIN`).  It seems to work if the fields aren't the result another group function.